# Angular js server side filter and pagination

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angularjs

I have a couple of input fields, we can use an input field with the name of search as an example. when someone types into that field i want to be able to filter the results of an object. but i want to do the filter server side not client side. i have a database with a lot of records so i don't want to have to return them all and do the filtering client side, it really slows things down. id also like to implement pagination with angular js. any pointers? or a direction i should head?

I use mongodb as a db store

Comment: This is a pretty broad/vague question. Certainly you can find examples around the web. If you have some code you're having an issue with or something more specific, that would make a better question.

Comment: why do you want to do filtering on client side mongo db provide very fast filtering of its own

Answer (score 5):

Here is the example using mongolab: http://jsfiddle.net/CLVpf/2/

You can just `$watch` the query variable to construct query URL,
and call `query()` against the `ngResource` instance.

```
$scope.$watch('search', function (key) {
    var q = null;
    if (key) {
        q = {
            q: '{name:{$regex:"' + key + '"}}'
        };
    }
    $scope.projects = Project.query(q);
});
```

Here `Project` is the ngResource instance.