# How to make a server side filter with angular js

Tags: angularjs

How to do server side filter with angular js? I have tried the code below and I can now do pagination but I can't do a filter.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if (input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }
});
app.controller('customersCrtl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $http.get('ajax/getCustomers.php?limit=' + $scope.currentPage).success(function(data) {
        $scope.list = data;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
        $scope.entryLimit = 5; //max no of items to display in a page
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list[0].total; //Initially for no filter  
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.list[0].total;
    });
    $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;

    };
    $scope.filter = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
        }, 10);
    };
    $scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
});
```

Comment: See if this could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696008/angular-js-server-side-filter-and-pagination

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this before - 
https://masteringmean.com/lessons/471-Building-a-Complex-Single-Page-Application-Part-6
Its about 6 mins long but it does explain how to add a $filter. It is in the context of another application, however it is easy enough to follow.